# How can I adapt the code in dll to the main code?

Tags: c#, dll

I am triying the adapt my function which is found in dll but I am newbie on using dll and dividing the code.
The code in the dll is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace gdll
{
    public class Class1
    {
        private Bitmap DoGray(Bitmap bmp)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < bmp.Height - 1; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < bmp.Width - 1; j++)
                {
                    int value = (bmp.GetPixel(j, i).R + bmp.GetPixel(j, i).G + bmp.GetPixel(j, i).B) / 3;
                    Color clr;
                    clr = Color.FromArgb(value, value, value);
                    bmp.SetPixel(j, i, clr);
                }
            }
            return bmp;
        }
    }

}
```

But how should I write the code in form1.cs. Form1.cs[Design] have two buttons and 2 pictureBox.The first button for the original picture,the second one is for the filtered picture.I wrote the code version without dll(I wrote the function to the same page)below:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Bitmap image= new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image);
            Bitmap gray = DoGray(image);
            pictureBox2.Image = gray;
        }
```

Of course it is not working while function at dll file.

And this is the codes at form1.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using gdll;


namespace dnmimage
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog sfd = new OpenFileDialog();
            sfd.Filter = "Image Files|*.bmp|All Files|*.*";
            sfd.InitialDirectory = ".";
            if (sfd.ShowDialog() != System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                return;
            }
            pictureBox1.ImageLocation = sfd.FileName;

        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Bitmap image= new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image);
            Bitmap gray = DoGray(image);
            pictureBox2.Image = gray;
        }
```

Comment: What exactly is not working? Does it compile? Does it throw any error? My best guess out of the blue is, that you didn't copy the dll to the build directory

Comment: No I added the dll.This is not about it.It is not getting compiled but this is normal because I should write the codes refering the dll codes but this is the point.I do not know how to do.I do not know how can I create the connection between that two files.

Comment: I guess you are using VisualStudio? If so you can add references to dll to your project. In order to do this, right click in the solution explorer on you project. Look for "Add references". Then you can select your dll

Comment: Yes I am using visual studio and that part of my question was solved thanks to the commands below and I have still some problems with the code and trying to fix that with the last suggestions.Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DoGray function is private. In order to make it visible outside your Class1 it must be [public](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/public). Further you should make it [static](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/static):

```
public static Bitmap DoGray(Bitmap bmp)
```

Next step is to reference the gdll dll (the one with your DoGray function) needs to be referenced from the WinForms project (the one with the Form1.cs file).
The easiest way to do this is to have both projects (WinForms project and the dll project) in the same Solution and use a project [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-add-or-remove-references-by-using-the-reference-manager?view=vs-2019).

[image]

Then right click on your WinForms project (the project that contains your Form1.cs file) and select “*Add Reference…*”

[image]

In the “Reference Manager” select “Projects” on the left side and check your gdll (the one with the Class1.cs file) and click ok.

[image]

Now you can use the DoGray function:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Bitmap image= new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image);
    Bitmap gray = gdll.Class1.DoGray(image);
    pictureBox2.Image = gray;
}
```

Comment: I really appreciate for your comprehensive explanation.The code that you wrote worked when I add System.Drawing.Common but I still have a little problem.It is getting compiled now but when I try to push the button2 I am getting this error=>Exception Unhandled:System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Failed to load file or assembly ''System.Runtime, Version=4.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'

Comment: @n_stckwff after the compilation the gdll.dll must be in the same directory as the WinForms application. If this is not the case, the gdll.dll will not be found when you start the WinForms app. So you should set the output path for the gdll.dll project to the same folder as the WinForms project (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-change-the-build-output-directory?view=vs-2019).